# UnsatisfiedLinkError on WIndows 10 workstation

Tags: java, windows-10

Our Java software fail in 90% with the following error on a Windows 10 Pro system:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: codecLib error
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.decode(CLibPNGImageReader.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.clib.CLibImageReader.getImage(CLibImageReader.java:497)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.getImageTypes(CLibPNGImageReader.java:117)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getRawImageType(ImageReader.java:681)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.clib.CLibImageReader.read(CLibImageReader.java:571)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.medialib.codec.png.Decoder.decode_init(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J
    at com.sun.medialib.codec.png.Decoder.decode_init(Native Method)
    at com.sun.medialib.codec.png.Decoder.<init>(Decoder.java:38)
    at   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.png.CLibPNGImageReader.decode(CLibPNGImageReader.java:75)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This error comes when you don't have provided library in your classpath. Try to set it: java -Djava.library.path= "your dll path"

Comment: We must not add a library on other windows sytems. com.sun.medialib... is a Java included library. Something in this particular installation causes the error.